# No template named index error

Tags: python, web.py, pythonanywhere

I am new to Python, and I am trying to run a web.py app with Python Anywhere, but I keep getting the `No template named index` error. I've modified `wsgi.py` to use the following:

```
import web
import MySQLdb

urls = (
  '/', 'index'
)

render = web.template.render('/home/user/templates/')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, are you actually using the literal string `'/home/user/templates/'`, or `'/home/rhpt/templates/'` (or whatever your username is)? Second, have you actually created that directory and put anything there? If not, of course you're going to get some kind of error trying to access it. Are you following some kind of tutorial? If so, which one are you following, and have you deviated from it at any point?

Comment: I solved this. I should've read the directions a bit better. It should be /home/<username>/

Comment: That was my first guess as to your problem. I'll write it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've used the literal path `'/home/user/templates/'`. Unless your username is actually `user`, there is no such directory, and therefore attempting to read the `index` template out of that directory is going to fail.

If your username is, say, `rhpt`, you'd change that to `'/home/rhpt/templates/'`.

Even better, you might want to use `os.path.expanduser('~/templates/')` instead of hardcoding your username. (Then you can give your code to a friend, or a client, and they can host it without having to edit the code.)